# How to create a Network Topology in a shapefile that contains only nodes(geometry points)?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, pgrouting

I want to use pgrouting with the shapefile but when I use :

```
alter table network.publictransport add column source integer;
alter table network.publictransport add column target integer;
select pgr_createTopology('network.publictransport', 0.0001, 'geom', 'id');
```

and then execute my dijkstra query it says that it can't run and that source column contains 'null' value!

I used POSTGIS 2.0 Shapefile and DBF Loader Exporter to load the files onto the postgis database!

Comment: Sorry, the question in the title is different than the explanation. This makes no sense. You cannot create  network out of a point data, if you have no information about the relation (ways) between the points.

Comment: Maybe you are assuming the tool is creating (somehow) nearest neighbor links among points?

Comment: @dkastl I have a shapefile with geometry points and I want to achieve network topolog so I can use pgr_dijkstra is there any chance I can do that?

Comment: You need to know how points are connected to each other, how their relation is to each other. Otherwise routing will not work.

Comment: @dkastl they are geometry points on a map.and  I want the road to be their connection. Should I "snap" them on the network? The road length should be the edge.

Comment: @drizo - once again - you have shapefile (or table) with geometry points, and now you want to : 
1. join this points with each other with straight lines to create graph 
OR 
2. use this points as start and destination and count shortest way between them using road network (from somewhere)??

Comment: @Jendrusk Thanks for asking.They are bus station and they are in a shapefile as geometry points. I want them on create network topology so I can find the optimum route for a given starting and an ending point ,independent of the layer. I want to run the pgr_Dijkstra and get asa  result a table that will lead me from the starting point to the ending using the nodes of the shp layer. I want to force the pgr Dijkstra go through the nodes of the shapefile and not produce a route on its own.

Comment: Please ask me whatever else you will need to answer my question!

Comment: @Jendrusk I want to force the pgr djikstra go through the bus stops ,start the route from the starting point and end the route at an ending point a user requested.I was thinking that this may be achived by snapping the points on a road network? So I can have the road length as an edge?

Comment: @drizo - OK, but still lots of unknown here :) 1. You don't need a route between bus-stops, but the distances between them should be real (by the roads) or euclidean (by straight line)? What about bus lines? Point of start don't have to be on the same line then point of destination... What about stops order? Buses are not always driving shortest way from start to destination... there could be situation when point D will be nearest to point A, but to get there you have to ride thru points B and C... What is your exact use-case? You're passenger or network architect?

Comment: @Jendrusk I need real route not euclidean. I need to force my routing to go rhough the bus stops-nodes.Like routing from one point to another.Hmm you confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of questions cause your question is too broad and subject is not as simple as it seems...

Writing complete resolution for you could take few hours (!!!) so I'll only write down my line of thinking, it should give you direction which way to go.

1. You have to achieve road network data to count routes... OSM should be good enough.
2. Convert data into graph - I prefer osm2po.
3. Import data into PostGIS
4. Get table with bus-stop relations (order of bus-stops in every line and direction)
5. Build table with segments of route (line x, direction forward, from stop n, to stop n+1, route (n)->(n+1), length, cost)
6. Create another topology on this table

After this work-flow you'll get topology with only static routes between bus stops so PGR should give you way through them.

Of course:

1. This is my opinion - it should work, but I don't give a head :)
2. There could be simplest resolution...
3. This is 'dumbest' algorithm cause you have to take into consideration timetable of buses, waiting time in beginning and while bus-change, choosing simplest variations of bus changes, and many(^many) more other 'special cases' to make it more real (=usable).

I checked post as community wiki - if someone want to expand it or change something - be my guest :)